# Is it necessary to fill in ms access object properties?

Tags: ms-access

I have been asked by our IT manager to create documentation regarding all of my access applications I have created.

One method I thought of was using the navigation pane, going into the object properties and filling in the all descriptions so future developers would know what each object is for. Is this a commonly accepted practice?

Comment: Showing the schema would be a good start, you could then annotate it, perhaps with Word or Visio: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Document-and-print-your-database-design-8bb56649-dd17-4d2e-b8dc-17dddd1ac91a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: If you want to kill a few trees, there is the Database Documenter on Database Tools tab.

Comment: You should ask what the purpose is. A skilled developer does not need documentation of self-explaining objects.

Comment: yep. does he just want names and descriptions of what they do, or details down to data types of every field?

Comment: Basically, from what I have gathered. I think he is just looking for documentation so support for the file is easy.